# Understand how to use apply and unapply

Tags: scala

I'm trying to get a better understanding of the correct usage of `apply` and `unapply` methods.

Considering an object that we want to serialize and deserialize, is this a correct usage (i.e. the *Scala way*) of using `apply`  and `unapply`?

```
case class Foo
object Foo {
    apply(json: JValue): Foo = json.extract[Foo]
    unapply(f: Foo): JValue = //process to json
}
```

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Firstly, `apply` and `unapply` are not necessarily opposites of each other. Indeed, if you define one on a class/object, you don't have to define the other.

## apply

`apply` is probably the easier to explain. Essentially, when you treat your object like a function, apply is the method that is called, so, Scala turns:

`obj(a, b, c)` to `obj.apply(a, b, c)`.

## unapply

`unapply` is a bit more complicated. It is used in Scala's pattern matching mechanism and its most common use I've seen is in [Extractor Objects](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/112).

For example, here's a toy extractor object:

```
object Foo {
  def unapply(x : Int) : Option[String] = 
    if(x == 0) Some("Hello, World") else None
}
```

So now, if you use this is in a pattern match like so:

```
myInt match {
    case Foo(str) => println(str)
}
```

Let's suppose `myInt = 0`. Then what happens? In this case `Foo.unapply(0)` gets called, and as you can see, will return `Some("Hello, World")`. The contents of the `Option` will get assigned to `str` so in the end, the above pattern match will print out "Hello, world".

But what if `myInt = 1`? Then `Foo.unapply(1)` returns `None` so the corresponding expression for that pattern does not get called.

In the case of assignments, like `val Foo(str) = x` this is syntactic sugar for:

```
val str : String = Foo.unapply(x) match {
  case Some(s) => s
  case None    => throw new scala.MatchError(x)
}
```

Comment: a bit weird that you called the int `str` but other than that, very nice explaination ;)

Comment: The point is that `str` is actually a `String` not an `Int`, because this is a very peculiar kind of extractor object :)

Comment: It would be good to mention that you don't have to return `Option` or `Some` in particular: https://hseeberger.wordpress.com/2013/10/04/name-based-extractors-in-scala-2-11/ https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/proposal-to-officialize-and-generalize-name-based-pattern-matching/2848/7

Comment: Unapply can return any object that has the `get` and `isEmpty` methods (e.g. `Option`) or a `Boolean`. https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/extractor-objects.html

Answer (score 10):

The `apply` method is like a constructor which takes arguments and creates an object, whereas the `unapply` takes an object and tries to give back the arguments.

A simple example:

```
object Foo {

    def apply(name: String, suffix: String) = name + "." + suffix

    def unapply(name: String): Option[(String, String)] = {
      //simple argument extractor
      val parts = name.split("\\.")
      if (parts.length == 2) Some(parts(0), parts(1)) else None
    }
  }
```

when you call

```
val file = Foo("test", "txt")
```

It actually calls `Foo.apply("test", "txt")` and returns `test.txt`

If you want to deconstruct, call

```
val Foo(name) = file
```

This essentially invokes `val name = Foo.unapply(file).get` and returns `(test, txt)` (normally use pattern matching instead)

You can also directly unpack the tuple with 2 variables, i.e.

```
scala> val Foo(name, suffix) = file
val name: String = test
val suffix: String = txt
```

BTW, the return type of `unapply` is `Option` by convention.

Comment: **apply** "takes arguments and creates an object" - Not necessarily. It's just a method. It doesn't _have_ to take, create, or return anything. It's often/usually a factory method, but that's just a convention. **unapply** "return type ... needs to be `Option`" - [Not true](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46897540/4993128). The use of `Option` is a convenience, not a requirement.

Comment: Should not `val Foo(name) = file` be `val Foo(name, ext) = file` ? We're expecting two arguments back.

Answer (score 5):

So apply and unapply are just defs that have extra syntax support.

Apply takes arguments and by convention will return a value related to the object's name.  If we take Scala's case classes as "correct" usage then the object Foo's apply will construct a Foo instance without needing to add "new".  You are free of course to make apply do whatever you wish (key to value in Map, set contains value in Set, and indexing in Seq come to mind).

Unapply, if returning an Option or Boolean can be used in match{} and pattern matching.  Like apply it's just a def so can do whatever you dream up but the common usage is to extract value(s) from instances of the object's companion class.

From the libraries I've worked with serialization/deserialization defs tend to get named explicitly.  E.g., write/read, show/read, toX/fromX, etc.

If you want to use apply/unapply for this purpose the only thing I'd suggest is changing to

```
def unapply(f: Foo): Option[JValue]
```

Then you could do something like:

```
val myFoo = Foo("""{name: "Whiskers", age: 7}""".asJson)
// use myFoo

val Foo(jval) = myFoo
// use jval
```