# Why I have to return Some in unapply method

Tags: scala

Why the following code doesn't work if I do not use `Some` in `unapply` method?

```
scala> object T {
     | def unapply(i:Int) = (i+1,i+2) //Some not used, I get error
     | }
defined object T

scala> 1 match {
     | case T(x,y) => println(x,y)
     | }
<console>:14: error: an unapply result must have a member `def isEmpty: Boolean
       case T(x,y) => println(x,y)
            ^

scala> object T {
     | def unapply(i:Int) = Some(i+1,i+2) //Some used. No error
     | }
defined object T

scala> 1 match {
     | case T(x,y) => println(x,y)
     | }
(2,3)
```

scala>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't. You have to return something that has an `isEmpty()` method and a `get()` method. `Option` provides both so that's a convenient solution.

This is how the compiler knows that the match has succeeded. If `isEmpty()` returns `true` then the match fails and the next match is attempted (if there is a next).

Answer (score 2):

```
  val bob = new Person("bobby", 28)

  abstract class Wrapper[T] {
    def isEmpty: Boolean

    def get: T
  }

  object PersonWrapper {

    def unapply(arg: Person): Wrapper[String] = new Wrapper[String] {
      def isEmpty = false

      def get: String = arg.name
    }
  }

  println {
    bob match {
      case PersonWrapper(n) => s"name is $n"
    }
  }
```

outputs: **name is bobby**

if `isEmpty` is set to `true`, then we will get `scala.MatchError`

Also, in other words,

```
  object even {
    def unapply(x: Int): Boolean = x % 2 == 0
  }

  object singleDigit {
    def unapply(x: Int): Boolean = x > -10 && x < 10
  }

  println {
    12 match {
      case singleDigit2() => s"single digit ...."
      case even2()        => s"even number......."
    }
  }
```

If `unapply` method returns `false`, we will get `scala.MatchError`

Comment: Hi @Aamir, thanks for the nice explanation. In the case statement singleDigit2() and even2() re mentioned. But there are no such methods. The code runs fine!. Can you please help how it works. Thanks!