# How to negate types in pattern match in Scala?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

With this code println will be executed only for specified exception. I'm wondering if it's possible to negate that line to make it executed for all other exceptions that are not specified. I know it's possible using 2 cases, but I want to know if it can be done with one case.

```
val myHandler: PartialFunction[Throwable, Unit] = {
  case e @ (_: MappingException | _: ParseException | _: SomeOtherException) =>
   println("Got it")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you've already identified what is probably the *more* readable way to do it.

```
val myHandler: PartialFunction[Throwable, Unit] = {
  case e @ (_: MappingException | _: ParseException | _: SomeOtherException) =>
    throw e
  case _ =>
    println("Got it")
}
```

This is probably how I'd write this in actual production code. It's sensible and it's clear at a glance.

But you asked for one case, so let's give that a go. Since we want to check against several types, we'll need to be able to represent them as a list. There are countless Scala libraries that make this prettier, but for our purposes we'll just roll our own.

```
trait TList {
  def isMember(x: Any): Boolean
}

object Nil extends TList {
  def isMember(x: Any) = false
}

case class Cons[H : ClassTag](val tail: TList) extends TList {
  def isMember(x: Any) = {
    x match {
      case _: H => true
      case _ => tail.isMember(x)
    }
  }
}
```

So we can represent classical Lisp-style singly-linked lists and check whether an arbitrary `Any` value has a type anywhere in the list. Now let's negate it and write an [`unapply`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18468786/understand-how-to-use-apply-and-unapply) method.

```
case class NotMember(val types: TList) {
  def unapply(elem: Any): Boolean =
    !types.isMember(elem)
}
```

Then our handler looks like

```
val test = NotMember(
  Cons[MappingException](Cons[ParseException](Cons[SomeOtherException](Nil)))
)
val myHandler: PartialFunction[Throwable, Unit] = {
  case test() =>
    println("Got it")
}
```

Again, if you really want to go down this road, you'll want to grab a library to make the type-level stuff manageable. But it's definitely possible. The only question is whether it's worth it for your use case.

Answer (score 6):

AFAIk you can not do this with a single match, but you can create your own custom **Extractor** in case you need to replicate this behaviour in multiple places.

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

final class Not[A : ClassTag] {
  def unapply(any: Any): Boolean = any match {
    case _: A => false
    case _ => true
  }
}
object Not {
  def apply[A : ClassTag]: Not[A] = new Not
}
```

which you can use like this:

```
final val NotAnInt = Not[Int]

10 match {
  case NotAnInt() => false
  case _ => true
}
// res: Boolean = true

"10" match {
  case NotAnInt() => true
  case _ => false
}
// res: Boolean = true
```

However, keep in mind this will have all the limitation of any type check, like not being able to differentiate between a **List[Int]** from a **List[String]** due *erasure*; and being considered a [bad practice](https://typelevel.org/blog/2014/11/10/why_is_adt_pattern_matching_allowed.html).

I would suggest looking into a **typeclass** approach, for example, I believe **Shapeless** provides a negation one.

---

*You can see the code running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/XxNfqLF2S2W7QbHFFNBH9g/4)*.